# Checking the content from an URL: Is it a file or webpage?

Tags: java, url, contains

I have an app which need different action based on the content from an `URL`. If the content is a file, I need to download it. But, if the content is a webpage, I need to open it. As far I know, there are two URL types:

- **Direct link**. For example: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-14_r04.zip
- **Undirect link**. For example: http://www.example.com/downloadfile?file=12345

And the example for webpage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/xxxxxx/how-to-check-a-url-contain

I only have the following code to parse a `String` to `URL`:

```
String requestUrl = "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-14_r04.zip";
URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
```

**So, my questions:**

- How can I check the content? Is it a file or webpage?
- If it's a file, how can I check the content from undirect link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open it and check the headers - if it is "application/html" it seems to be a web page.

Comment: text/html, but that's the idea.

Comment: In general, URLs do not map to the server's filesystem, even though many web servers like Apache do this by default, so you should consider a different approach (content-type header is good, if it's OK to connect to the URL). Consider web apps that might use URLs like http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/article and http://www.example.com/download/category/filename — the resource identifiers are unrelated to the filesystem or file names. Furthermore, sometimes you'll have http://www.example.com/downloadarea/file.zip which is in fact a webpage with info and a link to download the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check content type:

```
    URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
    String contentType = c.getContentType();
```

for html - `text/html; charset=utf-8`;
for zip  - `application/zip`

Answer (score 0):

Permit me to add my answer though this question is a year old.

Android provides a URL utility that can check many options based on URL.
Try:

```
        URLUtil.isFileUrl(URL)
```

Other options includes isDataUrl, isContentUrl etc.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, this answer is incorrect. isFileUrl() will return true, if URL starts with "file:", "file:///android_asset/" or "file:///cookieless_proxy/"